# Open easy responsive tab from a separate link on same page

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, tabs

Sharepoint site. Sample of html (active tab):

```
<div style="display: block; width: 100%; margin: 0px;" id="tabGroup1" class="tabs resp-vtabs">
<ul class="resp-tabs-list"><li role="tab" aria-controls="tab_item-0" class="list-item-0 resp-tab-item resp-tab-active">Meet the Team</li>
```

The script adds the "resp-tab-active" class when the li is clicked. I want a link on the same page (outside the div "tabGroup1") to override that function and open one of the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

you do something like this and wrap it around the link

```
<a onclick="Javascript:addclass('resp-tab-active', '.list-item-0')"> Click here to show tab</a>
```

then create a JS function to do what you need

```
function addclass(newclass, selector)
{
    $(selector).addClass(newclass);
}
```

the selector you pass through is the ID of the tab you want to show or the existing class.  it's a standard Jquery selector.

assuming this is part of a larger tabs,  you might want to remove active from others.

something like:

```
function changeActive(newclass, selector)
{
    var this = $(selector);
    var ul = this.parent();
    ul.children().removeClass(newclass);
    this.addClass(newclass);
}
```